# Вывод в консоль при отработке тестов в CLion

Tags: c++, логирование, тестирование, вывод, clion

Всем привет.

Пишу тесты с использованием Catch2. Все хорошо, все отрабатывает. Единственное, немного смущает вывод логов.

В Test Toolbar, где выводятся логи тестов и отображается, работают ли тесты или нет, формат вывода логов такой:

```
\x1B[01;37m[16:45:29][Info]: \x1B[22;37mHello
```

При этом, если мы говорим про вывод в обычную консоль CLion, все выводится хорошо:

```
[16:45:29][Info]: Hello
```

Может быть, кто-нибудь знает, как это исправить и исправляемо ли это вообще?

Comment: эти доп символы - цвета, просто оболочка их не понимает, вот и принтит как есть

Comment: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказали, это Catch2 пытается разукрасить консоль, но ошибочно решил, TestToolbar - консоль с поддержкой цвета. Но можно ему помочь - просто добавьте параметр

[--use-colour no](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/command-line.md#use-colour)

Если же параметр сложно прописать (я знаю, CLion немного странным бывает), то можно прям тестах прописать [CATCH_CONFIG_COLOUR_NONE](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#terminal-colour)